# Adding CheckBox and ProgressBar to WPF listView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm trying to add ProgressBar and CheckBox to ListView in WPF. But I cannot add both in DataTemplate. I can add either ProgressBar or CheckBox.

If I add it, It says more than once visualTree is set.

Below is the XAML of the app.

```
        <ListView x:Name="ApplicationList" ClipToBounds="True" Margin="0,100">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="ApplicationListGrid">
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Tag="{Binding Check}" IsChecked="{Binding Check}"/>
            <ProgressBar Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Progress}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Application Name" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Application Description" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Data Template can only contain a Single Item , however if that single item itself can contain multiple items then that is allowed

as such you should add a container to the data template and then add both your controls into that

Examples of containers are

- Grid
- UniformGrid
- Canvas
- StackPanel
- DockPanel

i would suggest a stack panel but the choice is yours

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox Tag="{Binding Check}" IsChecked="{Binding Check}"/>
        <ProgressBar Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Progress}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: What if I want to add the checkbox or progressBar at the end?

Comment: at the end of what?

Comment: End of columns, Last column should be progress bar. and first should be checkbox

Comment: in that case you need to add them in to two separate columns like you did with name and Description, you can't have a gridView where the first column is also the last

Comment: Thank you. Its working as I expected. (well, More than I expected)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a grid and then add checkbox and the progressbar.

```
        <ListView x:Name="ApplicationList" ClipToBounds="True" Margin="0,100">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="ApplicationListGrid">
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Tag="{Binding Check}" IsChecked="{Binding Check}"/>
                                    <ProgressBar  Grid.Column="1" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Progress}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Application Name" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Application Description" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: While your answer will fix the problem, you haven't explained why it happened or that grid is not the only option the OP can use